# Which cannon could fired this Austrian brass shell case (Berndorf 1910 R)?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, austria-hungary, artillery

I would like to know which cannon could have fired such a shell and what does the R stand for? Was it fired in WWI?

The dimensions are as follows: length 58 cm, width at the base 9.5 cm, and width at the top 8 cm. Are they rare?

[image: Base of cartridge case]

[image: side view of cartridge case]

Comment: possibly an 88 563r flak shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell was manufactured in 1910 at the [Wöllersdorf Works](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%B6llersdorfer_Werke) factory at Berndorf in Lower Austria (and nicknamed '*Krupp-Stadt*' or '*Krupp city*', which should give you some idea of what they're famous for!).

Shells manufactured in 1910 could certainly have been fired during the First World War.

---

The dimensions you've given look to be a pretty close match to the round for the [7.7 cm Flak L/35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7.7_cm_FlaK_L/35), (77 x 586R).  However, the 1910 date looks to be very early for that.

For what it is worth, the [Western Front Museum](https://ator1149.home.xs4all.nl/wfm/ww1/ammunition2.html) web site says they have one of these in their collection - although they designate it as the *8 cm Flak L/45K*.  Unfortunately, they don't have a picture on their web site, but it may be worth contacting them.

---

As for the 'R' stamp on German / Austrian munitions, that is a new one to me.  I'll need to do some more research there.

Comment: Thank you! I've emailed the Austrian Military History Museum for more information.

Comment: @Felipe That's great.  Do let us know what they say.

Comment: The Austrian Military History Museum hasn't responded yet. However, I reached an Austria-Hungary historian in twitter who thinks it might be a 10 cm round from a Skoda K10 naval gun. http://www.kuk-kriegsmarine.at/adspaun.htm

Comment: @Felipe Hmm.  I'd say that is unlikely.  The barrel of the [Škoda 10 cm K10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0koda_10_cm_K10) had a calibre of 10cm.  That means the internal diameter of the barrel was 10cm. According to your measurements, your shell case was intended for a weapon with a calibre of about 8cm (a more accurate measurement of the internal diameter at the top would help here).